# Combinatorics Concept Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box contains 5 white, 4 blue, and 7 red balls. What is the probability that each color is represented in a sample of four balls drawn at random and without replacement?

In the solution:

The  denominator I understand, namely, all of the ways to select 4 balls =  ${16 \choose 4}$

For the numerator, one is supposed to account for all of the ways to have all 3 represented, namely

A.  2W1B1R - ${5 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}{7 \choose 1}$
B.  1W2B1R - ${5 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{7 \choose 1}$
C.  1W1B2R - ${5 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}{7 \choose 2}$

Sum these for these for the numerator. Here is my (conceptual) question: In this part directly above, for example, in A, is this the product of all of these combinations accounting for all of the different ways that  2W1B1R can be expressed, for example WWRB, WRWB, WRBW.....?

Comment: Yes, it is. Irrespective of the order in which the balls are chosen, there are $\binom52$ possible pairs of white balls, $4$ possible black balls, and $7$ possible red balls. This calculation counts **sets** of $4$ balls, not **ordered lists** of $4$ balls.

Answer (score 1):

No white balls:$\binom{11}{4}$, no blue balls: $\binom{12}{4}$, no red balls $\binom{9}{4}$. Add back $3 (1+1+1)$ because you've counted 'only X balls' twice.